# How to receive binary data from a request in TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10, httpserver

I'm using Indy to build both a client and server application using HTTP. On the Client, I'm using `TIdHTTP` and on the server I'm using `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` with a web module. I need the Client to be able to post any type of data via a Stream to the Server. This is done through a universal command I have called `/set?Key=API_KEY&Name=FILE_NAME` where `Key` is the API Key for authentication and `Name` is the name of the file being posted.

On the client, I am posting the data like so:

```
function TInnoCloudClient.SetData(const Name: String; AStream: TStream): Bool;
var
  U: String;
begin
  U:= FServerURL; //Base URL of Server
  if Copy(U, Length(U)-1, 1) <> '/' then
    U:= U + '/';
  U:= U + 'get?Key='+Encode(FAPIKey);
  U:= U + '&Name='+Encode(Name);
  try
    FWeb.Post(U, AStream);
  except
    on e: exception do begin
      //Handle Exception
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This function is supposed to save the data inside `AStream` to a file on the server with the filename of `Name`. On the Server end, however, in the request handler, I see no corresponding `TStream` property in the Request which I can read this from.

In the Server, how do I acquire the data which I sent as a `TStream` descendant? I don't need to know how to save it or handle the request, just how do I obtain this Stream from the Request (`TWebRequest`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `TWebRequest.ReadClient()` or `TWebClient.ReadString()` method to read the posted binary data, or the `TWebRequest.RawContent` property to retreive the posted data as an `AnsiString`.

Something like this should work:

```
procedure TWebModule1.GetAllDataAsStream(ARequest: TWebRequest; AStream: TMemoryStream);
var
  BytesRead, ContentLength: Integer;
  Buffer: array[0..1023] of Byte;
begin
  AStream.Clear;
  ContentLength := ARequest.ContentLength;
  while ContentLength > 0 do begin
    BytesRead := ARequest.ReadClient(Buffer[0], Min(ContentLength, SizeOf(Buffer)));
    if BytesRead < 1 then Break;
    AStream.WriteBuffer(Buffer[0], BytesRead);
    Dec(ContentLength, BytesRead);
  end;
  AStream.Position:= 0;
end;
```

Comment: From what I saw in the Delphi docs and what my own tests seem to prove is that this code results in truncated content - the first 48k(?) will be missing. It's necessary to read `content` before calling  `ReadClient`, which retrieves only _the rest_  of the buffer after the first 48k of `content` .

Comment: I don't use WebBroker, so I can't say if that is true or not.  All I do know is that `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` uses `TIdHTTPServer` internally and exposes its functionality to WebBroker. The various `TWebRequest.Read...()` methods read directly from Indy's `TIdHTTPRequestInfo.PostStream` object if the client posted data, otherwise it reads from a `TStringStream` containing data from `TIdHTTPRequestInfo.FormParams` and `TIdHTTPRequestInfo.UnparsedParams`. So, if reading in the manner I showed above is missing data, chances are that it was already read prior to this code being run.

Comment: WebBroker's `Content` value reads from the same stream, and in the case of a client-posted stream, `Content` seeks the `PostStream` to the beginning, reads the entire stream, and then seeks it back to where it was previously, whereas the `Read...()` methods read from the current position onward.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - _chances are that it was already read prior to this code being run_  - I understand, yet i have code that seems to prove otherwise. A colleague sent me this link also along the same lines: [Re: Reading with IDThhp.Post sended data in ISAPI-DLL: data get messed up - Hello Remy,
sorry for the inconvenience but your code doesn't work:](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.internet.winsock/201111/1111216628.html)

Comment: I have never used DataSnap/WebBroker, so I can't comment on how it actually works. I can only comment on what I see in the `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge` source code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - OK can't argue with what you see in the code. My code is in a WebSnap ISAPI module. This is in the online help for Delphi XE  [HTTPApp.TWebRequest.ReadClient](ms-help://embarcadero.rs_xe/vcl/HTTPApp.TWebRequest.ReadClient.html)  _Use ReadClient **to get the next chunk of information** when the content of the request message is too large for the Content property._